# Is it possible to host web3 and solidity on google appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, solidity, web3js

Is it possible to host web3 and solidity on google appengine?

I am trying to put web3 and solidity on appengine standard environment, wondering if anyone done it and is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Web3 is just a library written in many flavors like JS, Swift, Kotlin and etc. You can install it inside your web or mobile application.

I assume you're building web DApp here. So, you can host it anywhere you want i.e. shared hosting, VPS, Heroku, AppEngine and etc. You also can host it on IPFS to make it fully decentralized.

Regarding Solidity, that's high level language to write smart-contracts. When you deploy smart-contracts to blockchain (public or private), it translates to bytecode and the EVM will read and operate based on this bytecode.

So, you can't simply deploy that smart-contract to a normal server. You need to deploy it to blockchain node.

If you're developing for Ethereum main net, you have 2 options:

1. Deploy it via [Infura](https://infura.io/)
2. Run you own Geth node for Ethereum main net and deploy into it

What Infura does is simple. It provides you managed blockchain node. All you need to do is just sign up, get the API key and put it inside your deploy script i.e. *truffle.js* file.

If you're developing for private blockchain, you also can deploy it to your Geth node for private blockchain. In private blockchain, you can choose to run Proof of Work or Proof of Authority.

I recommend you to use Proof or Authority for private blockchain. It require less compute and the blocks will be processed faster compared to Proof of Work which at some point later, you might face [memory leakage problem](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20high%20memory%20).

If you are looking for tutorial on how to install Proof of Authority private blockchain, you can refer this good [tutorial](https://arctouch.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ethereum-blockchain/).

I hope this helps.